# Are there Android devices without a camera, but with a torch?

Tags: camera-flash

Flashlight in Android seems to be "entangled" with Camera, leading to UI, power consumption, privacy and other issues.

Are there Android devices with a torch, but without a camera at all? How the LED is managed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any Android phone with a LED flash but without a camera. There might be a few low end phones(with a generic OS) that are available with a small LED for flash for using flash.

> Are there Android devices with a torch, but without a camera at all? How the LED is managed there?

Even if there is such a phone, Android has a [Camera API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) that will let the app control flash.

Comment: Camera API without a camera?

Comment: The API is a "feature" on Android not the camera itself.